# Когда А больше или равно В, но А минус В больше или равно 0?

Tags: python

Есть два числа — `А` и `В`. Программа выдала такой результат:

```py
А - В >= 0  # True
A >= В      # False
```

При каких значениях `A` и `B` такое может быть?

Comment: вроде никогда, т.к. `A-B>=0` можно преобразовать в `A>=B`, а это протеворечит второму условию, т.к. оно говорит обратное.

Comment: например -2 и -3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чёрная магия:

```py
A = 9007199254740992.0
B = 9007199254740993

print(A - B >= 0)  # True
print(A >= B)      # False
```

---

Поведение связано с типами чисел. Одно число представлено как `int` и имеет бесконечную точность в `Python`, а второе — как `float`, и его точность зависит от платформы.

На платформах [IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) мантисса чисел двойной точности содержит 53 бита:

```py
import sys

sys.float_info.mant_dig  # 53
```

Поэтому некоторые числа не могут быть точно представлены и округляются:

```py
x = 1 << 53       # 9007199254740992

y = float(x)      # 9007199254740992.0
z = float(x + 1)  # 9007199254740992.0
y == z            # True
```

Округление (из-за приведения типа) происходит при любых математических операциях, если хотя бы один из операндов имеет тип `float`:

```py
9007199254740992.0 - 9007199254740993
9007199254740992.0 - 9007199254740992.0 = 0
```

Но сравнение выполняется математически точно, приведение типов не требуется.